# Momentum Operator on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, metric-tensor, sigma-models

Consider a non-linear sigma model on a Riemannian manifold with metric $g_{ij}$ with the action

$$S= \frac{1}{2} \int dt g_{ij}(X) \frac{dX^i}{dt} \frac{dX^j}{dt}.$$

The momentum operator is $$P_i= \frac{\delta S}{\delta \dot{X}}= g_{ij} \partial_t X^j,$$
and $X$ and $P$ satisfy the commutation relation
$$[X^i, P_j]= i \delta^i_j.$$

Can we similar to the standard (flat) case identify
$$P_i= -i \hbar D_i,$$
with $D_i$ being the covariant derivative? If yes, why is this generalization correct?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111216/2451

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?