# Quantising Classical Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, quantization

Suppose you have a system described by the following Lagrangian: 
$$L=(1-gq²)\dot{q}^2/2.$$

How would you quantize this theory? Do you need to symmetrize the Hamiltonian before promoting the coordinate and momentum to operators?

Comment: What is usually understood as "canonical quantization" depends very much on whether the system is constrained. Can you check this?

Answer (score 2):

1. The 1D particle $L=\frac{1}{2}m(q)\dot{q}^2$ with a position-dependent mass $m(q)$ has classical momentum $p=m(q)\dot{q}$ and Hamiltonian $H=\frac{p^2}{2m(q)}$.
2. The Hamiltonian operator should be a self-adjoint operator. However this does not make quantization unique.
3. Following the same quantization strategy as my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111225/2451) where the mass $m(q)$ is viewed as the lone component $g_{qq}$ of a 1D metric, in the Schrödinger representation the momentum operator becomes
   $$ \hat{p}~=~ \frac{\hbar}{i} m(q)^{-1/4}\frac{\partial }{\partial q}  m(q)^{1/4}, $$
   and the Hamiltonian operator becomes
   $$ \hat{H}~=~ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2} m(q)^{-1/4}\frac{\partial }{\partial q}  m(q)^{-1/2} \frac{\partial }{\partial q}m(q)^{-1/4}. $$